# Jasper ireport Designer netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, report

i've created a GUI in netbeans and i've added the Jasper plugins and library. i want to be able to start Jasper iReport designer wizard with a button click from my GUI.note that when i click File>New File in Netbeans i find Report Wizard on the list of File Types. The thing is that i want to start the same report wizard from my GUI with JAVA code and not from Netbeans.

PS : Jasper iReport Designer creates a JRXML file.

i'm using this piece of code to generate the report, i just need a way to start the designer with JAVA code.The ireport designer generates the file **report1.jrxml** as shown in the code below.

```
public void genRapport() throws net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException{


        File r  = new File ("src/report1.jrxml");

    Map parameters = new HashMap();
    JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(r);
    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters,conn);
    JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint,false);
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "src/report1.pdf");

}
```

Comment: `File r  = new File ("src/report1.jrxml");` is a bad idea, you should consder using `URL r  = getClass().getResource("/report1.jrxml");` or use `Class#getResourceAsStream` instead

Comment: your response is irrelevant, it 's not what i'm looking for

Comment: Up until you deploy your up and you get a `FileNotFoundException`, then it'll become very relevant. But you are free to ignore it, that's why it's a comment

Comment: Also, you don't need the report designer, you need to "fill" the report with the data you want to display on the report.  Maybe you should have a look at [Filling Reports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jasperreports-library-tutorial#Filling_Reports)

Comment: i deployed and i didn't get any exception, everything is working perfectly, i didn"t find a way to start the designer with java code but instead i installed the ireport designer standalone version and runned it from my GUI and i got no problems creating report models or generating reports. thanks for your concern man :)

Answer (score -1):

```
JasperDesign jd = JRXmlLoader.load("src/report_new/report1.jrxml");

        JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);
        JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, null,new JREmptyDataSource());
        JasperViewer.viewReport(jp,false);
```

You can try this and add library:

[image]